# How I can get object attributes for different language codes in Django template?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-transmeta

I am using django-transmeta for translation. In the below code,   {{ obj.description }} returns the description in the current language of django. What I need is, getting the obj.description_[lang_code]. How can I get it?

```
{% for lang in languages.all %}
            <div id='{{ lang.code }}'>
                <input type="text" name="description-{{lang.code}}" value='{{ obj.description }}'/>
            </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Do you want to have Languages available in templates?

Comment: I want to get description_en, description_tr ... etc dynamically.

Comment: try `lang.0` for code and `lang.1` for name or description

Comment: I need something like {{ obj.description_{{lang.code}} }} which is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood from your comment you want to get description of specific language in `for loop`?

then simply write a [custom filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters) like in this way

```
{{ obj|get_lang_info:lang.code }}
```

here `get_lang_info` is custom filter.

Comment: Thanks, it should be like that. But I have a problem. With this code, filter cannot know if I am getting the 'description'. I should also send the information that I am getting 'description' or 'name' attributes.

Comment: can I assign {{ 'description_'|add:lang.code }} to a variable 'attr' and use it like  {{ obj|get_lang_info:attr }} ?

Comment: I think you need just description of given language, and this filter will only return description of that language.